# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL unix domain socket

Tags: centos, nginx, postgresql, php-fpm

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL Unix domain socket from a PHP web application. Relevant system components:

- CentOS 7 x64 (SELinux enforced)
- postgresql93 9.3.5-2PGDG.rhel7
- nginx 1.6.2-1.el7.ngx
- php-common 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
- php-fpm 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
- php-pdo 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
- php-pgsql 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3

PostgreSQL is listening on standard port 5432 and I have no problems to use it via TCP/IP at 127.0.0.1:5432, but when I try to connect to its Unix domain socket, I have a following error:

```
Cannot connect to database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server:
No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

File */tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432* exists and I can connect using **psql**:

```
$ psql -Uusername db_name
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

db_name=>
```

So there should be no problems from the PostgreSQL side. Or are there?

Relevant line from */var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf*:

```
local    all    username        trust
```

Change of location for Unix domain socket file in */var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf* did not help:

```
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/pgsql'
```

There was nothing in */var/log/audit/audit.log*, but I've tried to disable SELinux, just to be sure:

```
# setenforce 0
```

This did not help, so it is not SELinux.

Relevant lines from **strace** of **php-fpm**:

```
[pid   882] socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0) = 5
[pid   882] fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
[pid   882] fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid   882] connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid   882] close(5)                    = 0
```

The file name is correct and, again, file */tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432* exists:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
srwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 0 Nov  1 09:47 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

It looks like php-fpm process is not chroot'ed:

```
# ls -l /proc/882/root
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 0 Oct 31 19:54 /proc/882/root -> /
```

At this point I have no more ideas where the problem can be and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've resolved the problem. The initial cause of it was in systemd service file for php-fpm */usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service*:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
```

This means that php-fpm could not see */tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432* nor anything else located in */tmp*.
To resolve the issue I've changed the location for PostgreSQL Unix domain socket file with following steps:

- Create a new directory */var/pgsql* (note changing SELinux file context):

  ```
  # mkdir /var/pgsql
  # chown posgres:postgres /var/pgsql
  # chmod 0755 /var/pgsql
  # semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_var_run_t "/var/pgsql(/.*)?"
  # restorecon -R /var/pgsql
  ```
- Uncomment and modify **unix_socket_directories** parameter in */var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf* (*/tmp* is still needed not to break psql and other programs):

  ```
  unix_socket_directories = '/tmp,/var/pgsql'
  ```

And here was another tricky part... In the original post I wrote that I've tried to change the location of Unix domain socket file, and I really did. What I missed was the changed error message. I thought that the error was the same, but it wasn't:

```
Error (256): Cannot connect to database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to
server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

**Permission denied** - this is something one can fight.

Everything works with

```
# setenforce 0
```

The problem is:

```
# audit2allow -a

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

And it can be fixed:

```
# audit2allow -a -M httpd_postgresql_unix_socket_connect
# semodule -i httpd_postgresql_unix_socket_connect.pp
```

Content of *httpd_postgresql_unix_socket_connect.te*:

```
module httpd_postgresql_unix_socket_connect 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        type initrc_t;
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

Turn SELinux back on:

```
# setenforce 1
```

And everything works!

P.S. I'd be glad to know if there is a way to avoid custom SELinux module by changing some file contexts or booleans. It might be the case, because SELinux allows nginx to use php-fpm Unix domain socket (*/var/run/php5-fpm.sock*), but for some reason blocks usage of PostgreSQL Unix domain socket (*/var/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.5432*).